# Node.js Devices not found

Tags: ios, node.js, xcode, appcelerator

I installed Appc studio on MBP with C2D, OSX 10.9.5, XCode 6.2, can't update to newest Sierra and XCode, because MBP is not longer supported.
I have problem, I don't see any iOS simulators/devices connected to MBP. I tried to uninstall, install, reinstall, downgrade and upgrade node.js and also TiSDK(6.0.2&5.1.1), but after 
`appc ti info -t ios`
it throws error:
`Cannot read property "devices" of undefined`
When I open Xcode, I see my connected iPhone and iOS simulators.
Can please somebody help me?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If from Xcode you can see al the devices and you can start them, the problem is probably that Appcelerator "lost" the path to Xcode.
Check with `appc setup` if it's everything right and have a look also at the platform iOS properties.

Comment: Hi Mauro, I checked the paths to Xcode and everything seems normal. I tried to reinstall Xcode and Appcelerator as well, but nothing changed...

Comment: Sorry but I don't know what to say. If you think it could be a bug you could try to write on https://jira.appcelerator.org/, or try to ask in http://tislack.org/, there are a lot of Titanium experts there.